# Delete rows on the basis of another data frame if the data matched and insert new data

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-pandas

I have two files one is file1.csv and another one is file2.csv
I have put file1 data in one dataframe and when second file file2.csv will arrive then
I have to write a code in such a way that if second file data matches in first file data on basis of year and month columns then delete the data from file1 dataframe as it is old data and insert new file2 data in file1 dataframe

**File1.csv**

year  month  Amount

2022  Aug    12

2022  Oct    10

2021  Jan    20

2020  March  30

**file2.csv**

year month Amount

2022  Jan   220

2022  Feb   130

2022  Oct   100

**final output**

year month Amount

2022  Aug   12

2022  Oct   100

2021  Jan   20

2020  March 30

2022  Feb   130

2022  Jan   220

I have been trying if exists condition in pyspark but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my 2 cents:

1. Create 2 dataframes from 2 CSV files(in my case I'm just creating with static data)

   ```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import *
    from pyspark.sql.window import *

    data1 = [
    (2022, 'Aug', 12),
    (2022, 'Oct', 10),
    (2021, 'Jan', 20),
    (2020, 'March', 30)]

    data2 = [
    (2022, 'Jan', 220),
    (2022, 'Feb', 130),
    (2022, 'Oct', 100)]

    df_main = spark.createDataFrame(data1,schema = ['year', 'month', 'Amount'])
    df_incremental = spark.createDataFrame(data2,schema = ['year', 'month', 'Amount'])
   ```
2. Then Use row_number() on top of year and month and then once evaluated filter only such rows whose row_number is 1, and then drop the row_number column.

   ```
    df_merge = df_incremental.unionAll(df_main)

    windowSpec = Window.partitionBy('year', 'month').orderBy('year', 'month')
    df_merge = df_merge.withColumn("_row_number", row_number().over(windowSpec))
    df_merge = df_merge.where(df_merge._row_number == 1).drop("_row_number")

    df_merge.show()
   ```

Please find the below image for reference:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> if second file data matches in first file data on basis of year and month columns then delete the data from file1 dataframe as it is old data and insert new file2 data in file1 dataframe

You can do it with the following steps:

- do a `LEFT` join, to assign matching rows from `file2.csv` DataFrame into `file1.csv` DataFrame and NULLs if no match is found
- do a `when-otherwise` transformation on the `year-month` pair from `file2.csv` DataFrame: if columns you want to have in final output are NOT NULL - take these, otherwise, take those from `file1.csv` DataFrame.

More on `when-otherwise` transformation - https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-when-otherwise/

Comment: thanks for your inputs
If possible,can you please hard code your inputs